# Export more than 100k data sql server to excel using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Sheet1$", con);

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            //BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
            //bsource.DataSource = dt;
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;
            //sda.Update(dt);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Locale = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook("D:\\ChallanBulkUpload\\ChallanBulkUpload\\ChallanBulkUpload\\UploadFile\\challan.xls", ds);

        }
```

Comment: "For this reason my code doesn't work" what error do you get? have you tried selecting and inserting your data in batches?

Comment: when i click button , it show me This webpage is not available

Comment: Can you post the code invoked on the click of your button?

Comment: @Md.MehediHassan ok. really, what kind of debugging have you been doing? did you set breakpoints and step through your code? do you catch exceptions and log them to a logfile?

Comment: Now i tried different way. I'm updated the code that i posted. Please see it.  But give me error like Invalid cell value when i want to upload more than 50k data. But 35k data upload successfully.I want to upload more than 100k data. what's the problem ? please help me. I can't understand the problem.

Comment: What technology is `ExcelLibrary` using to make the workbook? It that your library or is it a 3rd party library. Some ways (Using `Interop.Excel` classess) [do not work from asp.net](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757).

Comment: No, it's not my library. Can you tell me, why it's not work properly? what's is the main reason? I want to develop it in C# windows forms application. Please help me to do this work or refer me some helpful link.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, using oledb to process excel files is a bit buggy.
I switched over to using OpenXml (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425).
Maybe also a solution for you ....

Update:
You can also use excel interop to process excel files (xls), see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(v=vs.80).aspx

For this to work, Excel has to be installed on the system.

Comment: FYI: OpenXml can not create `xls` files, it can only create the newer `xlsx` format that Microsoft switched to starting with Office 2003.

Comment: so, tell me what can i do ? I want to export more than 100k data from sql server to excel sheet with header. This will be C# windows forms application under button click.

Comment: You are not saying why @Poiter answer is not sufficient for you. You have not stated you need XLS format, and have not provided any feedback as to why the suggested answer is incorrect.